# Problems uploading an application to HEROKU, Failed with async. H12

Tags: javascript, express, github, heroku

when trying to deploy my app in heroku, I get this error: 
I'm trying to search the net but I can't find anything definitive. Just say that it works perfect for me at local. I use MAMP, the database is in myphpadmin and I think I imported it correctly in Heroku. The .env variables that I have are:

```
BD_NAME = agencydeviajes
BD_USER = root
BD_PASS = root
BD_HOST = 127.0.0.1
BD_PORT = 8889

HOST = localhost
```

My heroku variables:
[image]

And this is my repository: [Git HUB Repository](https://github.com/Lekanda/agenciadeviajesBueno)
I haven't been able to find a solution for more than a week and I'm a little desperate, I appreciate a lot of ideas. This is the error log.
[image]

I am new to Heroku and I am learning Java Script. Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can reference `localhost` on heroku. Try using postgres url instead, e.g: `postgres://dbUserName:dbPassword@db.server:dbPortNumber/dbName`.
 its easier to manage. Heroku has a postgres service to. You  could follow this [link](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) to learn more about the postgres addon on heroku

Comment: Thanks Mcdavid, but now the problem is diferent .At this moment I get this error, which is different from before, refers to H12, you know what it is.
Sorry but I needed to update the question.
Rookie stuff.

Comment: Can you get the full log, what you can do is open the log tab and try reproducing error, then you can get the full log for the error with the file its referencing

Comment: Thanks friend but I do not understand what you mean, the log of the fault is in the question, or is that not what you say?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The logs is the screen shot you sent it doesn't contain the full information of where the problem comes from because heroku shows you only a few lines if you weren't on the log page. To get more logs keep the log page open and try reproducing the error,so as to get the full logs

Comment: One more thing I see you're using es6, `async` `await` and you don't have babel configured. That could be also what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Mcdavid, thank you very much for your interest once again, I have updated the view log with the complete error, I thought it was whole but it is an error of mine. The repository is updated too, yesterday I broke the other one :))) In this update I have passed the files with async and await by babel and they work fine locally but still do not go remotely.
Finally, this idea that you give me,
where to put it? in the HOST ??
It's something new for me and I have to break my head a bit :)))
Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Comment: Are you setting your environmental variables on heroku, The way you declared in your database config file?

Comment: Hi Mcdavid, I have updated the Heroku variables in the post. I don't know what to look anymore. pufffff.
thank you very much friend.
And good night.

Comment: Do you have like a twitter handle or messenger so I could send you a dm, would be easier from there to communicate

Comment: Hi Mcdavid my Twitter id is @abernaolao, thanks my friend

Comment: Can't seem to send you a dm, seems locked

Comment: Mine is @mcdavid_95

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207881/discussion-between-lekanda-and-mcdavid).